# How can i know what is calling this script again and again causing multiple processes thread running at a specific time

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, linux-kernel

i have below script which starts an extract process for ETL. For few days, this process is being restarted at a specific time(23:30 hours) and leaving 3 PID's for the same process. SO I want to know what is calling this script again and again causing multiple processes thread running at a specific time.
Please help me find the root cause or configuring a log at least which can tell what is keep calling my script.

`cat StartExtract.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

## restart the Importation process after hot-stop or start it first time (DAIE)
. /opt/mycom/shell/admin.conf
CheckAppUser

ManualImportMode=`echo $* | grep "\-S" | wc -l`
IdScriptTag="Detl-extr "
if [ $ManualImportMode -gt 0 ]; then
   IdScriptTag="Detl-manualimport-extr "
fi

ExitIfIsProcessInstanceRunning "$IdScriptTag "

exec nice -n 19 $javaBin/java -$IdScriptTag -$XmsExtract -$XmxExtract -cp "/opt/mycom/jar/*:/opt/mycom/jar/lib/*:$JAVA_HOME/lib/*:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/*" -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/mycom/data/tmp $extractJvmExtraOption -Djava.awt.headless=true com.mycom.etl.extr.ExtractApp -C /opt/mycom/config RMI.Server=$rmiServer RMI.Port=$rmiPort $*
```

Comment: If the caller happens to wait for the process to complete, you could use top/ps/pstree to see the parent process. If nothing else you could get the user of the process in question.
But if I had to guess, do you have a cron job set up? (can check `crontab -e`)

Comment: Thanks for the response.....it doesn't wait for the process to complete, it just kills it in mid and restarts again and again resulting in multiple PID's . And i have checked my crontab, there is nothing scheduled to run around that time. Is there any way to configure a log what process/schedule has killed my process and started over ?

Comment: So there is only 1 instance of the script running at once? Your comment seems to imply the script is killed before a new one is spawned. Are you running it as a service (like via systemd)? If so then your system log may have useful info. Do you mind sharing the output of `ps aux` (just the lines containing the script in question). Also knowing what distro you're on may yield more targeted advice